# Link from Thumbnail to Post not working

Tags: post-thumbnails

i am trying to link my posts thumbnail to the post that it is pulling, however its not coming through as a link :S

```
<?php
    $carouselPosts = new WP_Query();
    $carouselPosts->query('showposts=3');
    ?>
    <?php while ($carouselPosts->have_posts()) : $carouselPosts->the_post(); ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><div class="recentpostthumbnail"><?php the_post_thumbnail(array(70,70)); ?></div></a>
         <div class="recentpostscontent"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>
         <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

I put the wrap round the actual div, is this the correct way to do this?

thanks

Comment: Works when I try it. I'd put the anchor around just the image though. You can wrap anchors around block level elements in HTML5 but not before.

Comment: thanks s_ha_hum i will try that. Maybe its just my chrome being idiotic

Comment: maybe im being stupid, but its not hyperlinking at all :S

Comment: Again, your code copied _verbatim_ works for me. Without more information I don't know what to tell you.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have more than one query in your page, let's make sure we are working with this query:

```
<?php
    $carouselPosts = new WP_Query();
    $carouselPosts->query('showposts=3');
    // checking if there are posts to show
    if($carouselPosts->posts){ 
       foreach ($carouselPosts->posts as $carouselPost) { 
        echo '<a href="'. get_permalink($carouselPost->ID). '">';
        echo '<div class="recentpostthumbnail">';
          echo get_the_post_thumbnail($carouselPost->ID,array(70,70));
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</a>';
        $excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
        if($excerpt)
             echo '<div class="recentpostscontent">'. $excerpt .'</div>';
        echo '<div class="clearfix"></div>';
      }
    }
```